# Usuário faz perguntas extras na área de comentários

Tags: debate

Eu respondi a seguinte pergunta a respeito da linguagem `R`: [Gráfico de Área e Linha no R com Eixo x como String](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182628/gr%C3%A1fico-de-%C3%81rea-e-linha-no-r-com-eixo-x-como-string/). O usuário viu minha resposta e não aceitou, embora ele tenha dado ciência de que a minha resposta respondeu a pergunta feita. Quando perguntei ao usuário se existia diferença entre a minha resposta e o que ele desejava, a [resposta dele foi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182628/gr%C3%A1fico-de-%C3%81rea-e-linha-no-r-com-eixo-x-como-string#comment378430_182787):

> Não tem mesmo. O gráfico está perfeito. Porém em outros datasets eu terei que colocar outras variáveis no segundo eixo y que não apresentam a mesma escala da variável do primeiro eixo y. Sei que tem uma função do ggplot que faz isso, mas não estou conseguindo inserir no código que me enviou. O nome da função é sec_axis.

Qual a etiqueta do SO neste caso? Eu deve dizer ao usuário que isto não estava na pergunta original? Afinal, segundo ele mesmo, eu respondi a sua pergunta original. Como a pergunta estava incompleta, eu não tinha como saber que esta outra feature era importante para ele.

No caso da etiqueta do SO ser responder a questionamentos extras em comentários que não fazem parte da pergunta original, como determinar onde parar?

Só para ficar claro, entendo que há vezes em que os respondentes não são 100% didáticos em suas respostas e faz sentido que hajam comentários pedindo maiores detalhes. Não creio que esta pergunta específica a qual me refiro caia nesta situação.

Comment: A pergunta que tu respondeu não esta clara, o AP poderia ser mais especifico em relação ao problema dele dando uma descrição melhor. Já a sua resposta me parece valida, só falta uma explicação da solução, não precisa ser longa. E lembres-se, uma resposta pode ajudar varias pessoas e não exclusivamente o AP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caso a pergunta não dê os detalhes completos e sua resposta for a solução para o que foi perguntado na questão acredito que já é o suficiente para o AP aceitá-la, o problema é que muitos não dão todos os detalhes, e esperam que quem responde adivinhe, em casos assim ACREDITO que o melhor a se fazer é:

Pedir para o AP detalhar o que falta na pergunta, e tentar complementar na resposta e orientá-lo a não complementar a pergunta no campo de comentários.

Answer (score 3):

## Resposta Curta

Num resumo geral, penso que se não está claro o suficiente e o AP posta complementos vitais nos comentários, tornando confuso, está muito claro o que fazer:

**Fechar** ⇨ **Não clara o suficiente**

## Resposta Longa

Normalmente aplico conforme a resposta do @FelipePaetzold mas evito "perder tempo" tentando orientar o AP a postar corretamente pois acho que isso ultrapassa a fronteira entre compartilhar o seu tempo agregando valor comunitário e "trabalhar de graça" para a empresa que mantém o SO.

Essa tarefa "minuciosa" deve ser da conta dos funcionários da rede SO pois ninguém aqui é pago para isso, exceto os funcionários. Os demais são todos voluntários.
Particularmente, dou uma única orientação ou abandono deixando a postagem a própria sorte.  Em casos onde foi inevitável onde eu dei alguma atenção, se o sujeito insistir em não postar corretamente, apenas voto para fechar como não "clara o suficiente" ou qualquer outro motivo que melhor se encaixe.

Claro que tudo tem um exceção. Por vezes, dá para tolerar e dar uma "forcinha". Mas fazer isso sempre, todas as vezes que acontece já consome muito do tempo. E tempo é dinheiro.