# Perguntas na pergunta

Tags: debate, perguntas, duvida

Respondi recentemente um usuário que tinha uma duvida de como melhorar a visualização de algumas informações em um gráfico do Google Charts, nos comentários da minha resposta o mesmo usuário começou a tirar outras duvidas relacionadas a outros temas, por exemplo:

*Como aumento o tamanho das barras?

Como crio um filtro para o gráfico?

Não consegui fazer o filtro...*

Não são temas tão diferentes assim, por isso respondi algumas destas perguntas para o usuário dentro da minha resposta principal, mas gostaria de saber se é aconselhável que eu responda ou aconselhe o usuário a abrir outra pergunta?

Vi outra pergunta semelhante aqui no Meta ([Usuário faz perguntas extras na área de comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5757/usu%C3%A1rio-faz-perguntas-extras-na-%C3%A1rea-de-coment%C3%A1rios)
), mas no meu caso a minha pergunta foi aceita,e as duvidas do usuário foram surgindo conforme as minhas respostas.

A pergunta do usuário foi essa:[Apresentação do gráfico na página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283185/apresenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-gr%C3%A1fico-na-p%C3%A1gina/283224?noredirect=1#comment578073_283224)

Comment: Dependendo da ralação da dúvida com a pergunta é melhor orientar o usuário a fazer outra pergunta, senão vai ficar ampla a pergunta dele e pode ser fechada.

Comment: O msm foi fazendo alguns comentário na minha resposta e eu respondi
Mas aconselhei-o a abrir outra pergunta quando as mesmas começaram a fugir muita da pergunta original, mas gostaria de saber se isso é valido msm ou foi algo rude da minha parte kkk

Comment: Cada caso é um caso. Eu diria que perguntas simples nos comentários _poderiam_ em sua bonança virar edições na sua resposta. Eu mesmo pergunto um ponto ou outro em respostas de perguntas alheias para que o AR faça uma resposta ainda mais completa. Claro, tento ser pequeno quando peço para o AR

Comment: Eu achei que o AP não entendeu sua resposta naquele comentário que você linkou...

Comment: Só li agora o seu comentário e o do Gato. Você fez mais que certo

Comment: Eu não sou Hard User nem muito experiente em programação, mas eu tento ajudar no que dá, já vi o comportamento semelhante em outras perguntas e a maioria do pessoal ignora

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> (...)nos comentários da minha resposta o mesmo usuário começou a tirar outras duvidas relacionadas a outros temas, por exemplo

Você se deparou com um [vampiro de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/o-problema-dos-vampiros-de-ajuda).

Diga ao usuário que se ele tiver uma dúvida diferente da original, que abra outra pergunta. E siga com sua vida sem deixar que ele te sugue.

Comment: kkkkkkk, foi basicamente isso que eu fiz, mas pelo o que eu vi, era novo aqui no SO, por isso a gente perdoa

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece com muita frequência. Quando é coisa simples, um detalhe ou algo até um certo limite, acho válido ajudar. Ajudando o usuário, dentro desses limites, você ganha a simpatia dele e com o tempo vai fazendo amizades, criando uma boa imagem.

Mas tem que ter um critério, como eu disse, um limite: quando as perguntas extras fogem muito da pergunta original e requerem tempo ou alteração considerável do código da pergunta (ou tema da pergunta), aí é bom sim orientar o usuário a fazer outra pergunta específica ao problema, como disse o @Renan.

Agora, quanto ao termo "*vampiro de ajuda*" acho um pouco pejorativo. Se você se sente *sugado*, não é obrigado a responder além do que foi levantado na pergunta original, mas veja o usuário de uma outra forma, principalmente os leigos e iniciantes. Instruí-los a entender o funcionamento do site, e que é melhor pra ele e para a comunidade fazer uma nova pergunta, é a melhor opção caso você não queira ou ache que não deve ajudar além do que já ajudou.

Ser atencioso, prestativo e gentil (se você dispõe dessas qualidades) com usuários iniciantes e inexperientes que supostamente querem te sugar, é sempre bom e vai lhe trazer bons resultados. Mas não confunda essas qualidades com ser "bobo". Adote critérios abalizados com as diretrizes do site, como as recomendadas na [página da ajuda be-nice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).